# mongolab throws auth error

Tags: mongodb, mlab

This question has been posted before in different forms but none of the answers seem to address my issue.

I'm trying to connect to a mongolab sandbox through the mongo shell but end up with Error: 18 Authentication failed.

I've tried making new dbUsers and they all throw the same error.

I'm using mongo version 3.0.7 and node version 5.0.0 so I don't think the driver update solutions apply to me.

Comment: What version of the mongo shell are you using? Ensure it's at least 3.0.0 if you're connecting to a 3.0.7 database.